# Avoid cmd.exe start closing Windows terminal

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a program of mine with a /realTime priority option. For that purpose I'm running on CMD:

```
cmd.exe /k start "MyProgram" /WAIT /RealTime "C:\Users\Me\bin\Release\MyProgram.exe" " option"
```

start will run the process MyProgram at the highest priority and when it finish however closes the window (the /WAIT parameter doesn't work in this case as it's not a matter of synchronizity). The /k parameter cannot catch in the same way the result of start command, as it closes itself. Do you know how can I use start command setting a priority without cmd closing my window terminal? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you want `cmd.exe` to continue running?  Use `cmd /k` inside of `start` instead of the other way around.

Comment: Do you mean : start /WAIT /RealTime cmd /k "C:\Users\Me\bin\Release\MyProgram.exe" " option" ? That runs cmd with RealTime priority, but not my program, which remains at normal priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The way to go is:

cmd /k start "C" /B /WAIT /RealTime "C:\Users\Me\MyProgram.exe" " option"

It's the only way I see to prevent start command closing windows. The /B param will run MyProgram in the same window, instead of opening a new one exlusively for the command. The cmd /k will do its work to prevent start closing the window when the program has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Given the **one** line of batch, what *should* happen is that the program starts and your batch windows should remain open until your program exits.

Are you expecting `/wait` to wait **after** `myprogram` has terminated?

If so, try

```
start "MyProgram" /WAIT /RealTime "C:\Users\Me\bin\Release\MyProgram.exe" " option"
pause
```

Comment: It's not a batch but a one-liner command. My post was edited to add a batch tag that I didn't include. I tried your batch solution but even with the pause command it closes the cmd window that is opened for "MyProgram"